# Necesito crear una "excepción" de variable numérica dentro de un switch que lee caracteres

Tags: java

tengo un switch que lee caracteres.

Algo así (por poner un ejemplo):

```
Scanner r = new Scanner(System.in);

char x;

System.out.println("Ingrese una letra correspondiente --> ");

x = r.next().charAt(0);

switch(x){

     case 'a':
         System.out.println("Esta es la letra a");
         break;
     case 'b':
         System.out.println("Esta es la letra b");
         break;
     default:
         System.out.println("intentalo de nuevo");
}
```

El programa tiene que ser susceptible a cualquier carácter no deseado a

excepción del número cero, en caso de ser el número cero, el programa tiene que

detenerse y no imprimir "Intentalo de nuevo"

¿De qué manera puedo crear esa excepción?, o de no ser el caso, ¿qué puedo hacer al respecto?

Comment: Bienvenido @Dirailandoi a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que intenteas hacer es que se detenga el programa cuando e ingrese el valor **cero** y que imprima **Intentalo de nuevo** cuando ingreses cualquier otro valor, esto te puede servir.

```
Scanner r = new Scanner(System.in);
char x = r.next().charAt(0);
while(x != '0'){
    switch (x){
        case 'a':
            System.out.println("Esta es la letra a");
            break;
        case 'b':
            System.out.println("Esta es la letra b");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("intentalo de nuevo");
    }
    x = r.next().charAt(0);
}
```

Para que funcione debes colocarlo dentro de una función y luego llamarlo en el método **main**, o incluirlo en este directamente.

Comment: gracias LázaroMER, aprecio tu apoyo, de hecho fue un buen consejo, aunque ahora que quiero utilizar el while que me recomendaste, precisamente java me arroja java.lang.RuntimeException, necesito saber que utilizar en esa circunstancia, pero reitero, gracias por la observación

Comment: Es necesario el código real y no un ejemplo para poder ayudarte. Mi respuesta parte del ejemplo que mostraste.